# Open a jquery get request in a new window

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make an ajax call to get data in a dropdownlist, call a controller and get the result in a new window.

So far I have tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#seeTemplates').click(function () {
        var template = $('#templates').val();

        alert("templateOpen!");

        alert(template);

        window.open($.get("@Url.Action("SeeTemplateDetailsByName", "EbayTemplate")", {
            templateName: template
        }));
    });
}
```

So when the user clicks on the links, I hoped the data obtained would be opened in a new window.

Here's the controller post:

```
public ActionResult SeeTemplateDetailsByName(string templateName)
{
    EbayTemplateInfo ebayTemplateToShow = mEbayTemplateManager.GetTemplateByName(templateName);

    if (ebayTemplateToShow == null)
    {
        TempData[MessageDomain.Tags.TEMPDATA_MESSAGE_ERROR] = NODATAFOUND;

        return RedirectToAction("EbayTemplateSearchIndex");
    }

    return View(ebayTemplateToShow);
}
```

And it is working normally, but the opened windows shows this:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Card/[object Object]

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34212
```

And the url goes like this: `http://localhost:63779/Card/[object%20Object]` And I don't understand why it is like that.

Comment: $.get on that url probably returns a JavaScript object, with properties within it. You'll need to expand the code slightly to assign the string you want out of the object that is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to `window.open`, which is not what it expects, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) what params needs to get passed.

Did you try just doing this:

```
window.open("/EbayTemplate/SeeTemplateDetailsByName?templateName=" + template);
```

Comment: Ah, no, I haven't. Will try it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did the trick! And thanks for the additionnal info.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is a get call, not a post. When you use $.get, the Razor is looking for a "[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]" as one of the Attributes on the controller. This makes sure that you are hitting the correct call and the application knows it is a "Get."
2. Make sure to have your JSON object match the incoming value on the controller. You can either make a model of the object you want to pass back to the controller and state that:  "modelOjbect templateName" OR you can just make sure you pass the object back as a string using JSON.stringify(templateName) in the params when you call the window.open("URL?templateName=" + JSON.stringify(templateName)).

Hope that helps!